# XAML Columndefinitions width * not taking available space

Tags: xaml, column-width

I know how the columndefinition works in XAML but there is something I want to do and don't know how.

I want 4 columns like that:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

1. column has fixed width
2. column must take all the available space (yes it is between columns and this is exactly the problem)
3. column has fixed width
4. column has fixed width

The 2nd column contains text and the problem is that when that text is too short the 2nd column does not take all the available space. it get's smaller automatically and this for each row. I can make it work with this code in the textblock:

```
MinWidth="2000"
```

But it's not the good way since this number could be too low when the screen is big.

**Here the whole listview containing the 4 columns:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding blabla}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Height="110" Width="110" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding blabla}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding blabla}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" MinWidth="2000" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" FontStretch="UltraCondensed"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding blabla, Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}}" Grid.Column="3" Width="76" Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Actually check your parent control width. That will not be getting set to the full width that you expected.

Comment: What do you mean? what parent control?

Comment: sorry not able express it clearly. But can you just investigate how much area you Grid is taking in Designer.

Comment: In the designer it looks perfectly nice. It takes the whole width of device. But when the app is launched in Simulator or real device the 2nd column automatically resizes to the needed text width. so when there is a short text then the 2nd column is really thin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your layout is well-defined but missed a small thing that is causing that the content of the Listviewitem is margined to the left because that is defined in the default ListViewItemStyle which is named "ItemContainerStyle" for the ListView Control .

All what you need to do is add this ListViewItemStyle that I've modified to stretch the content Horizontally and Vertically across all the available space for the item to your Resources

```
<Style x:Key="StretchedListViewItemStyle"
           TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

Then set it as the ItemContainerStyle for the ListView as follows:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding blabla}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedListViewItemStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Wow you found it! Didn't know that listview was styled like that. Thank you very much!