# Grid does not take 100% width

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following XAML code:

```
    <ListView Background="Blue" x:Name="lstFriends" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Pink">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Margin="12" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path='Fullname'}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"></TextBlock>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Path='OnlineIcon'}" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        </Grid>


                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path='Subtitle'}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Margin="12"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I already set `HorizontalContentAlignment`, as well as `ItemContainerStyle` as of these 2 articles:

[How to set width to 100% in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787436/how-to-set-width-to-100-in-wpf)

[XAML Columndefinitions width * not taking available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612621/xaml-columndefinitions-width-not-taking-available-space)

However, it still not works. The grid only take as much space as the `TextBlock`s and `Image`s need.

What did I do wrong? How can I make the Grid take all the space, and the OnlineIcon to the right?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>` in your *ListView.ItemContainerStyle*?

Comment: Nice finding! I had to changed from `HorizontalAlignment` to `HorizontalContentAlignment`. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding:

```xml
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
```

in `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>` should do the job.

You have mentioned about *HorizontalContentAlignment* in the question, but as I see you haven't set it in the xaml code. By default *HorizontalContentAlignment* is set to *Left*, thus it doesn't take all available space.